# Last Comment Name field is not removed after account cancellation

Tags: 7, comments, nodes

After cancelling the user under(`Delete the account and make its content belong to the Anonymous user`). Forum posted by is changed to "Anonymous" but 
comment name is still displayed in the forum.

[image]

Also i noticed it in the table, `node_comment_statistics`

[image]

How can i remove the Last Comment Name while cancelling, because i need to remove entire user information from my database.

**Update 1:**

Last_Comment_Name is mapped from the table `Comment` column `name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forum module doesn't respond to any user deletion activity so you'll have to build your own solution here. You can create a custom module with a  [`hook_user_cancel`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_cancel/7.x) implementation that will:

1. Check that the canceled user account is being anonymized.
2. Look up the username's entries in the `node_comment_statistics` (and other relevant tables).
3. Execute a `UPDATE` DB query that replace the name with "anonymous" (or whatever anonymized name you like).

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i did yesterday. Is this the recommended solution?

Comment: It's what I recommended :) The only better option I can think of (if it exists) is using a patch on the forum module to do the same thing. You might want to check d.o. forums to see if exists (seems like the forum module should do this automatically).